# How do I resize a combined shape while maintaining its proportion in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, resize

I made two gif images to describe what really my problem is.
Anyway on the first image, I've drew shapes individually and combined them all to make this logo. Unfortunately, its shape deforms whenever I try to resize it :-/ but I wonder why the messaging shape (the second image) does not deforms no matter how I resize it? Rasterizing the shape does not maintain the quality so it's a no for me :(
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do the sides of the first shape have a stroke applied to them? It appears as though the stroke is scaling, or not scaling, causing the issue.

Comment: I did not add any stroke on the first shape. This is my problem on creating logos and icons eversince I learned using Photoshop, it only happens on shapes that I combined with :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me...

1. Convert the multi-path shape to a smart object
2. Open the smart object by double clicking the smart object icon
3. Resize the smart object document using Image > Image Size

This forced Photoshop to scale the rounded corners proportionally, you will also be able to attain what ever resolution you want.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Good answer. You could also simply duplicate the shape layers to a new document, resize the new document via Image Size, then drag the layers back to the original document. You don't *have* to convert to a Smart Object.

Answer (score 4):

In my testing here..... live Rounded rectangles **do not** scale their rounding at all. If you set the rounding to 10px, it stays at 10px no matter how you scale the shape. That's your issue. You've got a rounded rectangle there to meet the ellipses and the corner rounding doesn't scale at the same rate as the ellipses.

You could adjust the rectangle rounding after scaling to match new size needed. Or if you select all the various shape layers and make them a **Smart Object** things will then scale as you are expecting.

Comment: I did not do a pixel-based comparison, but the round doesn't look like it scales *at all*. Might just be my perception playing tricks. This would explain why the rectangle appears to grow outwards.

Comment: @horatio edited.. after some testing here, you're correct. It's not a matter of scale rate, there's no scaling of the rounding in any way.

Comment: That's bad, but I'm thinking how other shapes made with rounded edges? and scaling them causes no issues at all, is there something to do with what they called as 'pathfinder'? Anyway that's the only way I can do icons and logos with the quality that maintains when I scale it but converting it as 'smart object' is like a rasterized shape :(

Comment: Smart objects are not rasterized in any way. They maintain all the original vector data. You lose **nothing** by converting the shape to a Smart Object.

Comment: I don't think it maintains it http://i.imgur.com/TvFN19C.jpg I converted the shape and scaled it up, the proportion is perfect but the quality is not...

Comment: It's giving you the pixel preview, but the shapes are all still vector. The only other option is to use the pen tool and draw the shape you need rather than using rectangles and ellipses.

Comment: I tried it and saved it as .png image, viewed on the browser but still, the smart object gives an awful quality :/ And lol I gave up using pen tool, it's hard to make every inch and pixel of its proportion to be uniform :(

Comment: It does take practice. Using Illustrator and copy/pasting as a shape layer would be easier in my opinion. Photoshop's Pen Tool is a bit lacking.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're resizing multiple shapes in the first one where the second one you're only resizing a single shape. Save a 2nd file, try flattening one of them and then resizing it.